# How to pass ng-repeat filtered list to custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to pass the result of an ng-repeat with a filter into a child directive, but I am getting an infinite digest cycle error.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zdkKm93JuTWUc7k1iY9H)

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/latest/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
    <thead></thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in (filteredItems = (list | filter: evens))">
      <td>{{x}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td footer-directive="" repeat-ctrl="repeatCtrl" list='filteredItems'></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

## JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("repeatCtrl", function($scope) {
  var foo = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    foo.push(i);
  }
  $scope.list = foo;
  $scope.evens = function(val) {
    return (val % 2 === 0);
  };

});

app.directive('footerDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: 'List: {{filteredItems}}',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { //Infinite digest loop
      scope.$watch('filteredItems', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can see that the filtered list is properly populated, but there's an infinite digest loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

I should have been using $watchCollection instead of $watch on the filteredItems

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `require:` and everything under `scope:` -- Read more about Isolated Scopes here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive & here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9554

Also, you don't need `controller:function()` if you have `link:function()`

Your directive should look more like this:

```js
app.directive('footerDirective', function() {
return {
    template: 'List: {{list}}',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.list)
    }
}});
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I've made those edits to the code. I'm still unsure how to trigger a function when the list is filtered though. I put a $watch on scope.filteredItems, but it still leads to an infinite digest loop